# What can I change in buttonadd in the section I think there is a problem

Tags: android-studio

```
     package com.example.gymmanagment;
     import static com.example.gymmanagment.Trainignactivity2.Training_key;
     import android.app.AlertDialog;
     import android.app.Dialog;
     import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.EditText;
       import android.widget.Spinner;
      import android.widget.TextView;
       import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
      import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
      import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
    public class plandetailsdialogue extends DialogFragment {
    private Button buttondismiss,butoonadd;
    private TextView txtname;
    private EditText edittextmintues;
    private Spinner spinnerdayy;
    public interface passplaninteface{
        void getplan(plan plan);
     }
    private passplaninteface passplaninteface;
    @NonNull
    @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View 
       view=getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialoguedetails,null);
            intiviews(view);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(view)
                .setTitle("enter details");
             Bundle bundle=getArguments();
             if(null !=bundle){ Training training=bundle.getParcelable(Training_key);
             if(null!=training){
                 txtname.setText(training.getName());
                 buttondismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View view) {
                              dismiss();
                          }
                      });
                      butoonadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View view) {
                              String day=spinnerdayy.getSelectedItem().toString();
                              int 
                         minitues=Integer.valueOf(edittextmintues.getText().toString());
                              plan plan=new plan(training,minitues,day,false);
                             try {
                            passplaninteface=(passplaninteface) getActivity();
                                     passplaninteface.getplan(plan);
                                     dismiss();
                              }catch (ClassCastException e){
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                                  dismiss();
                              }}
                      });
                       }
                        }

        return builder.create();
    }
    private void intiviews(View view){

        buttondismiss= view.findViewById(R.id.buttondissmiss);
        butoonadd= view.findViewById(R.id.onlyadd);
       txtname= view.findViewById(R.id.txtname234);
        edittextmintues= view.findViewById(R.id.edttxtminutes);
        spinnerdayy= view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerdays);
        }
         }
```

The error is below:

```
 022-01-29 13:20:54.963 8688-8688/com.example.gymmanagment E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.gymmanagment, PID: 8688
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:801)
    at 
   com.example.gymmanagment.plandetailsdialogue$2.onClick(plandetailsdialogue.java:52)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at 
 
com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your EditText is probabbly empty. The error shows that input string is: "". You can't assign a value of *nothing* to an Integer. You should check if EditText isn't empty before casting it to an Integer.

Try something like this:

```
if(!edittextminutes.getText().toString.isEmpty())
{
    //cast to Integer
}
```